# quick binomial probability question

Tags: probability

okay the question is;

probability of passing an exam is let's say 0.8, then what's probability of 10 people passing the exam, what's probability of 9 people passing the exam?

Now I know this is binomial probability distribution and this is my solution

a)(0.8)^10 = 0.1073741824
b)(0.8)^9 * (0.2) = 0.0268435456

but most of my friends tell me the solution to b is:
b)C(10,9) * [(0.8)^9 * (0.2)] = 0.268435456

so I don't really understand how is the 2nd probability higher than the 1st one, and **why** do we do that?

Comment: With the way it is currently written, the correct answer should be $0.8^9$ only.  There is no indication that there needs to be a person that fails the exam.

Comment: How many people are taking the exam? If you don’t know that, then the binomial distribution is inapt.

Answer (score 1):

What you have computed on answer B is the probability of 1 specific student not passing the test. Realise that any of the 10 students can be the one that fails the exam. It's not the same if Student 1 fails that if Student 2 fails. You have to take account each student failing separetly and add the probabilities up. The binomial counts the number of combinations you can make where 1 student fails (unordered combinations). That's why the answer is 10 times the one you wrote.

A tree diagram (where each branch division represent each student) could help you visualise this.

I apologise for my English, if anyone could rephrase my answer would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that 10 students are to be randomly selected, the reason why we have ${10 \choose 9} (=C(10,9)) $ Because there are 10 arrangements of the people who pass the exams. Our outcomes are strings of length 10 like for example $1111111110$ where $1$ means passing the exam and $0$ means not passing.

Now, to answer your question: In how many ways can you place one $0$ and $9$ 1's in a string? Well that is certainly ${10 \choose 9} = 10 $. Therefore, the desired probability is ${10 \choose 9} 0.8^9 \cdot 0.2 $

Answer (score 0):

We do that because all the persons are different. What you found is the probability that first 9 pass the exam and the last one failed. But the case when any one of the 10 fail the exam and others pass sis also valid. Hence you need to multiply it by C(10,9) which gives the ways to select 9 people who will pass the exam.